# Ruby - Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having issue running tests in different test environments (ip address or domain name) via terminal.

I am running this below to get error connection refused error

```
./testkit -s http://192.16.0.1
```

Error code shown was:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.9/lib/restclient/request.rb:206:in `transmit'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.9/lib/restclient/request.rb:68:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.9/lib/restclient/request.rb:35:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unirest-1.1.2/lib/unirest.rb:62:in `internal_request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unirest-1.1.2/lib/unirest.rb:48:in `request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unirest-1.1.2/lib/unirest.rb:96:in `get'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/services/delivery_service.rb:16:in `get_delivery_option'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suites/merchant_suite.rb:83:in `provision_delivery_option'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suites/merchant_suite.rb:29:in `provision_merchant'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/cases/case0.rb:31:in `run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suite.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suite.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suite.rb:42:in `block in run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suite.rb:36:in `each'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit/suite.rb:36:in `run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit.rb:44:in `block in run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit.rb:43:in `each'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit.rb:43:in `run'
from /Users/simonjoshi/work/ptk-test/lib/testkit.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

I tried to find for possible solution but couldn't find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that server at that address is up and reachable.

Comment: Telnet to IP gives me its connected and can access via browser as well. Also it works when run from intelliJ.

Comment: try starting the server at host using `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` to allow access from other ip

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Solr (sunspot), start solr instance first.

I also encountered this error once.